# Remove Obsolete ClickPass Login Option

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, openid

The expanded login options still includes a button for the ClickPass service.

However it's impossible to use because [the ClickPass service has been discontinued](http://janrain.com/clickpass-acquired-by-janrain/):

> The Clickpass service was acquired by Janrain in 2012 and is no longer active. If your website has been accepting logins through Clickpass, you are invited to migrate your site’s authentication to Janrain Engage social login. [...]
>
> If you have been using Clickpass to log in to any websites, please contact the website administrator to access your account with those websites.

> [image]

The ClickPass button should be removed from the expanded login options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Geoff took it out yesterday, change was deployed a bit earlier today.

Bye bye ClickPass.